# How do I compare times in TIMESTAMP columns with times (hH:MM:SS) in String format columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery SQL (Oracle background) and I'm struggling to compare times (in TIMESTAMP format) from table 1 that lie between start and end times stored in table 2 in string format.

Which of the plethora of TIMESTAMP, EXTRACT or format functions could I use to write sql to identify endtimes from table 1 that fall between starttime and endtime in table 2?

Table 1

```
Row starttime           endtime  
1   2018-07-20 06:45:00 UTC null     
2   2018-07-20 06:45:00 UTC 2018-07-20 08:58:08 UTC
```

Table 2

```
Row starttime   endtime  
1   06:45:00    06:50:00     
2   14:45:00    14:50:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery STandard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT t1.starttime, t1.endtime
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
ON TIME(t1.endtime) BETWEEN PARSE_TIME('%T', t2.starttime) AND PARSE_TIME('%T', t2.endtime)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, TIMESTAMP '2018-07-20 06:45:00 UTC' starttime, TIMESTAMP '2018-07-20 06:48:08 UTC' endtime UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2018-07-20 06:45:00 UTC', '2018-07-20 08:58:08 UTC'
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '06:45:00' starttime, '06:50:00' endtime UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, '14:45:00', '14:50:00' 
)
SELECT t1.starttime, t1.endtime
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
ON TIME(t1.endtime) BETWEEN PARSE_TIME('%T', t2.starttime) AND PARSE_TIME('%T', t2.endtime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison as strings:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on format_timestamp('%H:%M:%S', t1.endtime) between t2.starttime and t2.endtime;
```